# Cassandra C# driver mapper

Tags: c#, cassandra

Basic rules of Cassandra data modeling recommend us to create tables per query pattern.

> In practice, this generally means you will use roughly one table per
>   query pattern. If you need to support multiple query patterns, you
>   usually need more than one table.

For example, we can have this 3 tables for *Users*

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
    id uuid,
    username text,
    emial text,
    role text,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_by_role(
    role text,
    userid uuid,
    username text,
    emial text,
    PRIMARY KEY (role)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_by_email(
    email text,
    userid uuid,
    username text,
    role text,
    PRIMARY KEY (email)
);
```

And in C# using Cassandra CSharp driver we map *User* to the first table:

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id;
    public string UserName;
    public string Email;
    public string Role;
}

var config = new MappingConfiguration();
config.Define(new Map<User>()
   .TableName("users")
   .PartitionKey((o) => o.Id)
   .Column((u) => u.Id, (cm) => cm.WithName("id"))
   .Column((u) => u.UserName, (cm) => cm.WithName("username"))
   .Column((u) => u.Email, (cm) => cm.WithName("email"))
   .Column((u) => u.Role, (cm) => cm.WithName("role"))
   .ExplicitColumns());
UserMapper = new Mapper(Session, config);
```

and read data using Mapper:

```
User result = UserMapper.Single<User>("WHERE id=?", guid);
```

My first question is: How do we map *User* to the other two tables *users_by_role* and *users_by_email*? I don't think that we have to create 2 more CLR types with the same properties. (Besides, we can have different columns in other tables)
And the second question: How can we utilize defined mappers in BatchStatement? For example: to insert a user to first table we'd use:

```
UserMapper.Insert<User>(usr);
```

But in our example we have to insert to 3 tables in a batch. What is the best approach?

driver version 3.1.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is something that cannot be done.
You will have to proceed with mapping the 3 to each of the cassandra models.

Cassandra Table <=> c# Object.

When accessing them, based on the type of search (email, id or role), you'll need to create a level of abstraction, and this will return the user.